# How to add values to array dynamically if you move from one view controller to another viewcontroller in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

In `Add_EditAddressViewController` i need to show all added address in tableview, for that i have created one ARRAY and appending values to array in `NewZoomAddressViewController` to show in tableview but all the time i am getting single row in table view..  **so here how to add value to array dynamically without replacing into oldvalue in Add_EditAddressViewController**

**and navigation is:**

```
Add_EditAddressViewController: butnTap -> ProfileVC: btnTap -> NewZoomAddressViewController: btnTap -> Add_EditAddressViewController
```

here each time when i come to NewZoomAddressViewController need to append `\(self.sublocalityName!) \(localityName!) \(self.zipName!)` to **addressArray** to show in tableview of Add_EditAddressViewController

**Note: here i have added this question related code in github: https://github.com/SwiftSamples/AddressBug    here in profileVC you need to tap on map or continue Button then it navigates to NewZoomAddressViewController**

```
class Add_EditAddressViewController: UIViewController,DataEnteredDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var addeditTableview: UITableView!
var addressArray = [String]()

var city: String?
var pincode: String?
var locality: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addeditTableview.register(UINib(nibName: "EditAddressTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell")
    print("zoooom valuew \(pincode)")
    addeditTableview.reloadData()
}

}
extension Add_EditAddressViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return addressArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: EditAddressTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditAddressTableViewCell") as! EditAddressTableViewCell

    cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editbuttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell.nameHeader.text = "header"
        cell.addressLabel.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

**NewZoomAddressViewController code:**

```
class NewZoomAddressViewController: UIViewController {
weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil
var addressModel: ProfileModelUserAddress?
var addressArray = [String]()

var zipName: String?
var localityName: String?
var sublocalityName: String?

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("in Zoom map VC")
    mapView.delegate = self
    addressLabel.text = "\(self.sublocalityName!) \(localityName!) \(self.zipName!)"

}

@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add_EditAddressViewController") as! Add_EditAddressViewController
    addressArray.append("\(sublocalityName ?? "") \(zipName ?? "") \(localityName ?? "")")
    viewController.addressArray = addressArray

    print("total address array all rows \(viewController.addressArray)")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}

}
```

please try to help to display all added address in tableview. i got stuck here from long time.

Comment: how you go from `Add_EditAddressViewController` to `NewZoomAddressViewController` through back button ? or you write some code ?

Comment: @jawadAli `Add_EditAddressViewController ` to `profileViewcontroller` from here to `NewZoomAddressViewController ` using button pushviewcontroller

Comment: so you initiate  new `NewZoomAddressViewController` each time .... thats why array got initiated every time

Comment: @jawadAli, correct then how do i get all values to table view.. if i am doing in wrong way.. guide me to right way

Comment: @jawadAli please try to post answer to append each time to `addressArray `

Comment: @jawadAli could you show us the code for appending `"\(sublocalityName ?? "") \(zipName ?? "") \(localityName ?? "")"` each time to array to show in `Add_EditAddressViewController `

Comment: @iPhoneIOS Also mention about the flow, how user moves from one ViewController to another.

Comment: show your complete navigation

Comment: @udbhateja, i have edited and added only this code in github, please have a look and do  help with code

Comment: @jawadAli, edited my post with complete navigation, try to help with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **NewZoomAddressViewController** replace confirm button action with

```
@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    for controller in navigationController?.viewControllers ?? [] {
        if let listController =  controller as? Add_EditAddressViewController {
            let string = "\(sublocalityName ?? "") \(zipName ?? "") \(localityName ?? "")"
            listController.addressArray.append(string)
            navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

In **Add_EditAddressViewController** reload TableView on viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=true
    addeditTableview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: i need to send same `addressArray` to two view controllers Add_EditAddressViewController, and profile view controller how please let me know

Comment: Create a variable in these controllers of type String i.e `var array: [String] = []`

From you current VC when you initialize object of Add_EditAddressViewControlle & ProfileViewController just pass this array before pushing to navigation.

Comment: i am unable to save the added array in `Add_EditAddressViewController ` i will share code in github will you please solve the question as well

Comment: i am talking about this question.. i will mark your question as correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259218/added-tableview-data-is-not-coming-why-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Well what you need to do is to have address array in your profile view as well to pass it to other controller.. so your code becomes

First you will have array in profile like this

```
class ProfileAddressViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, DataEnteredDelegate {
   var addressArray = [String]()
}
```

Then when you call `NewZoomAddressViewController` you pass that array to them like this

```
@objc func triggerTouchAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Please Help!")

        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController
            viewController.delegate = self

        viewController.zipName = self.pincodeField.text
        viewController.sublocalityName = self.colonyField.text
        viewController.localityName = self.cityField.text
        viewController.addressArray = addressArray
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
    }
```

And in your `Add_EditAddressViewController` where you call profile.. assign array to profile

```
@objc func editbuttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        print("in button")
         let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileAddressViewController") as! ProfileAddressViewController
        viewController.addressArray = addressArray
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: thank you, here also new value replaces in tableview